# Find indices of the elements smaller than x in a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

Assuming that I have a numpy array such as:

```
import numpy as np    
arr = np.array([10,1,2,5,6,2,3,8])
```

How could I extract an array containing the indices of the elements smaller than 6 so I get the following result:

```
np.array([1,2,3,5,6])
```

I would like something that behave like [np.nonzero()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html) but instead of testing for nonzero value, it test for value smaller than x

Comment: Should the elements be sorted? Or was that simply a "possible" outcome?

Comment: `"but instead of testing for nonzero value, it test for value smaller than x`". So, test it? You have already mentioned `np.nonzero`.

Comment: to build on the hint from @Divakar, `False` values evaluate to zero

Comment: yes after reading Psidom answer, I felt a bit silly.

Answer (score 12):

You can use `numpy.flatnonzero` on the boolean mask and *Return indices that are non-zero in the flattened version of a*:

```
np.flatnonzero(arr < 6)
# array([1, 2, 3, 5, 6])
```

Another option on 1d array is `numpy.where`:

```
np.where(arr < 6)[0]
# array([1, 2, 3, 5, 6])
```

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way one can do this is by

```
arr[arr<6]
```

Comment: This will give the *values* not the indices

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest a cleaner and self-explainable way to do so:
First, find the indices where the condition is valid:

```
>> indices = arr < 6
>> indices
>> [False, True, True, True, False, True, False]
```

Then, use the indices for indexing:

```
>> arr[indices]
>> [1, 2, 5, 2, 3]
```

or for finding the right position in the original array:

```
>> np.where(indices)[0]
>> [1, 2, 3, 5, 6]
```